# timedatectl without using named zone

Tags: timezone

The typical way to set the timezone is to use `timedatectl`, e.g.:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

So I can use a named zone, or `UTC`.

But how do I set the zone without a name - e.g. `UTC-5` or `UTC+10` or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite inconvenient indeed.
This is kind of lame to suggest but you could list all available timezone names with `timedatectl list-timezones` and look for a region or city name that you know is located in the UTC timezone you are interested in. Sorry, I know that is not the answer you were looking for .....

Comment: That is more or less what I did, but I don't want to hardcode the name as it needs to be dynamic. Are you implying that this is not possible with `timedatectl` and I need to fall back to one of those older TZ tools?

Comment: I don't know if it's not possible but man timedatectl gives no indication how it could be done. Have a look at man localtime(5) perhaps. There is mention of UTC (quote:  .... identifier such as "Europe/Berlin" or "Etc/UTC" ...) That's just a hint, have not used it myself.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated/) is more helpful